# Inject values into html function via jQuery on modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, frontend

I have a trigger button for modal, passing the **id** and **value**.
In script section I need "inject" the **form** into modal-body.
**My problem is pass the variables in the html function of the script**. How do it?

**html**

```
<button value="{{ $etapaano->trabalho_id }}" id="{{ $etapaano->id }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" title="Enviar Arquivo" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalUploadArquivos"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Enviar</button> 

<div id="myModalUploadArquivos" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Submeter Arquivo</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="modalBodyArquivo" class="modal-body">

            </div>   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
$('#myModalUploadArquivos').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {        
    var $modal = $(this);
    var etapaanoid = e.relatedTarget.id;
    var trabalhoid = e.relatedTarget.value;         

    $('#modalBodyArquivo').html('<form method="POST" enctype=multipart/form-data action="{{ url("arquivo/store/etapaanoid/trabalhoanoid") }}" file="true">{{ csrf_field() }}<label for="descricao">Arquivo *</label><input type="file" name="descricao" /></div><div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button><button id="enviaArquivo" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" title="Enviar Arquivo">Enviar</button></div></form>');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
"{{ url("arquivo/store/etapaanoid/trabalhoanoid") }}"
```

With this:

```
"{{ url("arquivo/store") }}/'+etapaanoid+'/'+trabalhoanoid+'"
```